# Python is there an easier way to define multiple zeroed matrices?

Tags: python, matrix, variable-assignment

I'm currently defining two matrices with

```
A, B = matrix(zeros(shape =(3,3), dtype=complex)), matrix(zeros(shape =(3,3), dtype=complex))
```

I would like to use something like

```
A, B = 2*(matrix(zeros(shape =(3,3), dtype=complex)),)
```

However, in the second case any change made to A now changes B too.

I would like to be able to make multiple matrices of this type on a single line without using the first method as it's too long, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
A, B = [matrix(zeros(shape=(3,3), dtype=complex)) for _ in range(2)]
```

The reason your first attempt didn't work is that you're assigning the same array to A and B. Why? Well, `(matrix(zeros(shape =(3,3), dtype=complex)),)` is a tuple of one matrix. Doubling it gives you a tuple of the same matrix twice. Then you unpack that into two variables, which end up referring to the same matrix.

There's nothing specific to numpy arrays here; it happens with plain old Python lists, or even ints (although in that case you don't care—unlike arrays and lists, ints are immutable, so having two references to the same number `5` is just as good as having two separate number `5`s would be).

This confuses enough novices that there's a [FAQ question](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list) to explain it.

Anyway, using a comprehension allows you to evaluate the same expression repeatedly. Of course normally you use the loop variable, to evaluate it with a different value each time, but that isn't required. In this case, we want both matrices to be constructed the same way, so I just tossed the loop variable into `_` and ignored it.